# Нужно удалить строку из таблицы при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет мне нужно чтобы на экран выводило таблицу с данными и возле каждой строки была кнопка "Удалить пользователя" при нажатии на которую удалялась бы строка из таблицы и базы данных
Вот код вывода таблицы из которой нужно удалить:

```
<?php
include_once("connect_bd.php");

$tub = "SELECT * FROM users_list ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 10";
$resultat = mysqli_query($link, $tub) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ". $tub);

mysqli_close($link);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat))
{?>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="name"><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
<td id="email"><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
<td id="number"><?php echo $row['number']?></td>
<td id="country"><?php echo $row['country']?></td>
<td id="time"><?php echo $row['time']?></td>
<td id="del"><a href="delete_tub.php?=id<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
<button type="submit">Delete user:<?php echo $row['id'];?> </button>
</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Вот код вывода удаления записи:

```
<?php
include_once("connect_bd.php");

if(!empty($_GET['id']))
{
$del = "DELETE FROM users_list WHERE `id` = '{$_GET['id']}'";}

if ($link ->query($del) === TRUE) {
$res = ' http://localhost/testing_form/tub_users.php?success=TRUE';
}
else {
$res = ' http://localhost/testing_form/tub_users.php?success=false';
}
header("Location: {$res}");
$del->close();
echo "User Delete!";
?>
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку "Удалить" информация не удаляется (перебрасывает на ссылку http://localhost/testing_form/tub_users.php?success=false) помогите уже три дня пытаюсь решить эту проблему (может посоветуете какой то другой способ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все у вас верно за исключением одной строки: `<a href="delete_tub.php?=id<?php echo $row['id'];?>">` вы ошиблись в написании ссылки нужно `delete_tub.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']` равно не там поставили.

Comment: Это ответ самый простой и логичный выход из ситуации, ответ на четвёрочку: человек просит хлеб - и вы ему даёте хлеб. Однако, хороший ответ содержал бы ещё и что-то, что позволило бы сделать решение чуть лучше. Например, вы могли бы объяснить, что лучше использовать не ссылку с GET-параметром, а форму с одной кнопкой и hidden-полем: когда передача идёт через POST это намного безопаснее, чем через GET. А то я размещу на своём сайте картинки с url вида site.ru/delete_tub.php?id=1 и погрохаю половину базы.

Comment: @AK Человек спросил почему не работает, возможно он изучает php я указал на ошибку. Я могу добавить много замечаний, но по условиям сайта я не должен разглагольствовать а должен помочь, если я могу.

Comment: @AK, сомнительная безопасность, если она держится только на type=hidden у поля с важной информацией) Такие вещи нужно проверять на стороне сервера - позволено ли этому юзеру удалять из этой таблицы? позволено ли ему удалить эту конкретную запись (если, например, записи делятся по принадлежности к юзерам). Ну и, учитывая, что конечная стопроцентная проверка есть, то всё остальное - излишне: и эти манипуляции с get/post, и всякие валидации параметров через javascript и что еще можно придумать только.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Безопасность держится не на hidden, она держится на том, что запрос имеет тип POST, а не GET. Если пользователь авторизован на сайте и ему покажут картинку с url на удаление -- он сам всё удалит и даже не поймёт. Правильнее, конечно делать ещё одноразовые токены, но как правильно сказал Руслан Семёнов -- это уже достаточно далёкое отступление от первоначальной темы.

Answer (score -1):

Кнопка должна быть в форме отправки, чтобы данные отправлялись( в action указываете путь - куда надо передать данные. В вашем случае - id)

```html
<form action="connect_db.php">
//ваша таблица 
<button>Delete</button>
</form>
```

Гляньте примеры: [на w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) по формам ( да и вообще полезный ресурс)